# Linq to XML query returns null

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header/>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="en">
        <seg>Hello?</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="es">
        <seg>¿Diga?</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

And I'm trying to use this code to retrieve the content of the first `<seg>` tag:

```
root.Elements("tuv")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("lang").Value.Equals("en"))
    .Select(e => e.Elements("seg"))
    .SingleOrDefault()
    .Where(d => d.Value.Equals(originalText))
    .SingleOrDefault()
    .Value;
```

`originaltext` equals "Hello?" in this case. However, the result given is null. I assume my linq query is wrong. Could anyone give me a hint on how to write this query properly? Thank you very much!

Comment: Because `root` doesn't have an `Element` "tuv".

Comment: Indeed - you might want to use `Descendants`. You can also simplify your code using `==` rather than calling `Equals`, e.g. `e.Attribute("lang").Value == "en"`. I'd also *strongly* advise using one LINQ operator (i.e. method call) per line - lay your code out vertically and it'll be much easier to read. Next, `SingleOrDefault` returns a single value... you don't want to use `Where` after that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @JonSkeet How can I specify a single <seg> with a given content without using SingleOrDefault and where?

Comment: You probably want the Where *before* the SingleOrDefault. Filter to the right sequence, then take its only element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Elements` function returns a collection of the direct child elements of the `root`. You should use the `Descendants` method that return the collection of all descendant elements.

```
root.Descendants("tuv").Where(e => e.Attribute("lang").Value == "en")
                       .Select(e => e.Elements("seg")).SingleOrDefault() 
                       .Where(d => d.Value == originalText).SingleOrDefault().Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. So Elements wasn't working because "tuv" is not a direct child... I didn't know that it worked like that... my bad. :S

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the first "seg" element, do this

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\sample.xml"));

var firstSeg = xDoc.Descendants("seg").First();
```

Code to satisfy OP's requirement in comment

```
var seg = xDoc.Descendants("tuv")
                .First(tuv => tuv.Attribute("lang").Value == "en")
                .Element("seg")
                .Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would only work for this example. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Arturo then, can you please state clearly what is your selection criteria?

Comment: Select the content of a <seg> inside a <tuv> with attribute "lang" == "en". The answer given by Lukas Kabrt worked. Thank you anyway :).

Comment: Updated answer as per your requirement.